# Understanding this derivation for Rayleigh's Identity

Tags: fourier-series

I'm having trouble understanding [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Quk2v.jpg) proof of Rayleigh's Identity. More specifically, I'm not too comfortable with the summation notation. Firstly, I'm assuming that
$$ \displaystyle\sum_ i \sum_ j =\displaystyle\sum_ {i,j}$$
If this assumption is true, then I'm not following the proof. It seems you can just take the product like so:
$$ \displaystyle\sum_ i^ \infty x_ i  \sum_ j^ \infty x_ j = \displaystyle\sum_ {i,j}^ \infty x_ i x_ j $$
Can you really do this and just multiply the sums like that? Isn't this incorrect since for example
$$ \displaystyle\sum_ {i=1}^ 2 x_ i  \sum_ {j=1}^ 2 x_ j = x_ 1^ 2 +2x_ 1 x_ 2 + x_2 ^ 2 $$
where as
$$ \displaystyle\sum_ {i,j=1}^ 2 x_ i x_ j = x_ 1^ 2 + x_ 2^ 2 $$
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your understanding of the notation $\Sigma_{i,j=1}^{2} x_{i}x_{j}$ is incorrect.

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Comment: $\Sigma_{i,j=1}^{2} x_{i}x_{j}$ is conventionally taken to mean $\Sigma_{i=1}^{2} \Sigma_{j=1}^{2} x_{i}x_{j}=x_{1}^{2}+2x_{1}x_{2}+x_{2}^{2]$.